# VBscript and InStr function

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to retrieve the 5 characters before and after the string "Major-General" in the Pirate's of Penzance Major-General Song (found here: http://www.naic.edu/~gibson/poems/gilbert1.html ). I'm trying to find a better way to do this than what I have and also trying to figure out why it isn't looping. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
l1 =INSTR(l2, string, "Major-General")
l2 = 5
l3 = 1
vcount=0

if vcount <5 then
    l1 =INSTR(l3, string, "Major-General")
    vcount = vcount +1 
    word = mid(string, l1-5, l2 )
    word1 = mid(string, l1+13, l2)
    l3 = l3+l1
    response.write "<br>" & "5 before: " & word & "<br>"  & "5 after: " & word1 
end if
```

Comment: _"trying to figure out why it isn't looping"_ well because actually I don't see any loop in that code...

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a better way to do this than using mid() this way? It seems clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to do it like this:

```
Dim Poem,aStr,i,block,Left5,Right5

Poem = "The abc poem is abc in this abc string."

aStr = Split(Poem,"abc")

If uBound(aStr) = 0 Then Response.Write "String not found": Response.End

For i = 0 to uBound(aStr)
  block = Trim(aStr(i))
  Left5 = "": Right5 = ""
  if cStr(i) <> cStr(uBound(aStr)) then Left5 = Right(block,5)
  If cStr(i) <> cStr(0) then Right5 = Left(block,5)

  Response.Write "The 5 characters to the left of abc:" & Left5
  Response.Write "The 5 characters to the right of abc:" & Right5

Next
```

This will get the 5 characters to the left and right of the string, each time the string exists.

In this case, it will search the `Poem` string for `abc` and split the string into an array of each part where the string exists, then it can be processed further.